# Can't seem to register Broadcastreceiver dynamically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, intentfilter

I'm pretty new to android, and I've been trying to register my Broadcastreceiver dynamically so I could receive smss , but I just can't seem to make it work, here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hellllo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
}
```

The "hello" Toast wont pop up so I'm assuming the receiver was not registered

I put this permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Is your `Activity` in the foreground when you receive the SMS? Are your permissions outside of the `<application>` tags? What's your `targetSdkVersion`, and which version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: The Activity is in the foreground when I'm receiving the SMS.
The permissions are outside of the <application> tags.
minSdkVersion 16.
targetSdkVersion 23.
Testing on android 4.2.2 API 17.

Comment: Do you have another SMS app installed which might be intercepting the broadcast? Like Hangouts, or GoSMS?

Comment: I've wattsap installed . 
But when i register a receiver in the manifest it does work. It's only when i try to register it dynamically that it doesn't work

Comment: What `priority` do you set on the `<intent-filter>` when you register it in the manifest?

Comment: <intent-filter android:priority="999">

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what WhatsApp sets its priority at, but it might be intercepting. Try calling `filter.setPriority(999);` before you register the Receiver. Also, you should really be registering your Receiver in `onResume()`, and unregistering it in `onPause()`.

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!  
Thanks Mike you're the best!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. I'll post an answer a little later, when I get a chance. I want to check into WhatsApp's settings.

Comment: One more question Mike , Why is it better to register the receiver in onResume() and unregister it in onPause(), rather than register it in onCreate() and unregister it on onStop() ?

Comment: And btw, I did find hangout on my phone so that might have been the cause for the priority problem

Comment: Ah, OK, as long as you're unregistering the Receiver somewhere, so it doesn't leak. That was the main point. It's probably not gonna cause problems to do it where you are; I'd just say most users do it in `onResume()`/`onPause()`. Also, I would say that it's actually Hangouts that's intercepting and aborting that broadcast. I didn't have time to dig too far into WhatsApp's code, but it seems that they dynamically register their Receiver in a `Service`, though I didn't find exactly where. I know Hangouts sets its `priority` to `3`, I believe, to get the broadcast right before the platform app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determined in comments that the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast was being intercepted and aborted by another app. This was possible in Android prior to KitKat (API 19), but it is not in versions since.

The solution was to set the priority on the `IntentFilter` instance to `999`, using the `IntentFilter#setPriority()` method.

Please note, however, that it would still be possible for another app to abort the broadcast before yours receives it. Though the docs say that Receivers with `IntentFilter`s at the same priority will be delivered the broadcast in an arbitrary order, it usually pans out that they're delivered in the order that the apps were installed. Furthermore, it is possible for some apps - e.g., system apps, pre-installed apps, etc. - to have their priority higher than `999`, which is the maximum practical value for your app.